# Android - unregisterReceiver concept in detail?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am confused with `unregisterReceiver()`. Is it mandatory to unregister a receiver if we have registered it earlier in our code. I have seen that sometime we don't unregister it and still everything works fine but sometime we need to unregister it in order to get rid of run time exception.

Please explain the concept in detail and if possible with example. I have tried reading few books but none of them has explained it so if you know some book which could have a great explanation about it, let me know.

I would really appreciate your efforts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not mandatory to unregister your receiver. If you don't unregister it, the receiver continues to receive the Intents it's registered for from Android. You should unregister it when you don't wish to receive any more broadcasts.

Comment: Furthermore, Android will throw an exception when your Activity is suspended and the receiver not unregistered.

Answer (score -2):

this example might help..

better learning with an example

```
   package com.commonsware.android.shaker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShakerDemo extends Activity
  implements Shaker.Callback {
  private Shaker shaker=null;
  private TextView transcript=null;
  private ScrollView scroll=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    transcript=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.transcript);
    scroll=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);

    shaker=new Shaker(this, 1.25d, 500, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    shaker.close();
  }

  public void shakingStarted() {
    Log.d("ShakerDemo", "Shaking started!");
    transcript.setText(transcript.getText().toString()+"Shaking started\n");
    scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
  }

  public void shakingStopped() {
    Log.d("ShakerDemo", "Shaking stopped!");
    transcript.setText(transcript.getText().toString()+"Shaking stopped\n");
    scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
  }
}






package com.commonsware.android.shaker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Shaker {
  private SensorManager mgr=null;
  private long lastShakeTimestamp=0;
  private double threshold=1.0d;
  private long gap=0;
  private Shaker.Callback cb=null;

  public Shaker(Context ctxt, double threshold, long gap,
                  Shaker.Callback cb) {
    this.threshold=threshold*threshold;
    this.threshold=this.threshold
                    *SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH
                    *SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
    this.gap=gap;
    this.cb=cb;

    mgr=(SensorManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mgr.registerListener(listener,
                          mgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                          SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  public void close() {
    mgr.unregisterListener(listener);
  }

  private void isShaking() {
    long now=SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (lastShakeTimestamp==0) {
      lastShakeTimestamp=now;

      if (cb!=null) {
        cb.shakingStarted();
      }
    }
    else {
      lastShakeTimestamp=now;
    }
  }

  private void isNotShaking() {
    long now=SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (lastShakeTimestamp>0) {
      if (now-lastShakeTimestamp>gap) {
        lastShakeTimestamp=0;

        if (cb!=null) {
          cb.shakingStopped();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public interface Callback {
    void shakingStarted();
    void shakingStopped();
  }

  private SensorEventListener listener=new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
      if (e.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        double netForce=e.values[0]*e.values[0];

        netForce+=e.values[1]*e.values[1];
        netForce+=e.values[2]*e.values[2];

        if (threshold<netForce) {
          isShaking();
        }
        else {
          isNotShaking();
        }
      }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
      // unused
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I gave this a -1 because it doesn't even use a broadcast receiver.  How is this a helpful example?